# macros, splice, and pattern matching

Tags: scala, macros, pattern-matching, scala-2.10, scala-macros

Is there a way to use an argument to a macro in a pattern match? I would like to do this:

```
def extr(X:AnyRef) = macro extrImpl

def extrImpl(c:Context)(X:c.Expr[AnyRef]):c.Expr[AnyRef] = {
  import c.universe._

  val tree = reify {
    new {
      def unapply(x:String):Option[String] = x match {
        case X.splice => Some(x) //error
        case _ => None
      }
    }
  }.tree
  c.Expr(c.typeCheck(tree))
}
```

But unfortunately the compiler says "stable identifier required, but X.splice found". Normally, one would solve this by assigning to a val first, such as:

```
val XX = X.splice
```

But of course that doesn't work with splice either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible right now (and won't be possible in 2.10.0-final), but we have something in works that might help in subsequent point releases :)

Comment: but it would work if I constructed the tree manually (i.e. without reify) ?

Comment: btw, is it a bug that I have to use the c.typeCheck-workaround here again?

Comment: yes it would work with manual tree construction. speaking of typecheck, currently this is a known problem. i don't know whether we have a bug for that, but that's definitely something i would like to fix.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako would you mind giving a short example of how a pattern match would be constructed manually?

Comment: Sure, what tree do you want me to construct?